# Getting the correct sscanf format to print a string and integers

Tags: c, printf, scanf

How should the `sscanf` argument look like if I want the output of the print statement to be: `Saturday March 25 1989`

In other words I want the `date` to contain both `Saturday` AND `March`. I tried different `sscanf` format options but the print statement usually comes out gibberish.

```
int day, year;
char date[50], dtm[100];
strcpy( dtm, "Saturday March 25 1989" );
sscanf( dtm, "%s %d %d", date, &day, &year );

printf("%s %d %d\n", date, day, year );
```

Comment: Sarah, "...  contain both `Saturday` AND `March`" needs detail.  Should `date[]` contain "Saturday March", "Saturday March ", (note trailing space) or what?  What if `dtm`[]` begins with spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `sscanf` `%s` will get only *Saturday* because of the space then `%d` will try to extract an `int` from *March* and of course cannot

but you can do :

```
sscanf( dtm, "%[^0-9] %d %d", date, &day, &year );
```

or better

```
sscanf( dtm, "%49[^0-9] %d %d", date, &day, &year );
```

to not take the risk to write out of *date* (49 rather than 50 to let the space for the ending null character).

So

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int day, year;
  char date[50], dtm[100];
  strcpy( dtm, "Saturday March 25 1989" );
  if (sscanf( dtm, "%49[^0-9]%d%d", date, &day, &year ) == 3) /* remove useless spaces in format */
  
    printf("'%s' %d %d\n", date, day, year ); /* use '%s' to show all from date */
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'Saturday March ' 25 1989
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

as you can see the date memorizes the separating space *after* the date up to the day number, it is not possible to avoid that in your case because the length of the date is variable, but you can bypass the possible spaces *before* using `sscanf( dtm, " %[^0-9]%d%d", date, &day, &year );` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int day, year;
  char date[50], dtm[100];
  strcpy( dtm, "   Saturday March 25 1989" );
  if (sscanf( dtm, " %49[^0-9]%d%d", date, &day, &year ) == 3)
    printf("'%s' %d %d\n", date, day, year );
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'Saturday March ' 25 1989
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that *dtm* is useless and you can do directly :

```
if (sscanf("   Saturday March 25 1989",
    " %49[^0-9]%d%d", date, &day, &year ) == 3)
```